# Adding scale animation for CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, material-design

I'd like to implement transition animation between two UIView according to the material design as shown on screenshot below (first part of animation only):

[image]

But I'd like to make it more realistic with applying animated mask to UIView. Here is a code I've developed:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // 1. make a hole in self.view to make visible another view
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];
    [maskPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:sender.center
                                                        radius:sender.frame.size.width/2.0f
                                                    startAngle:0.0f
                                                      endAngle:2.0f*M_PI
                                                     clockwise:NO]];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.fillRule  = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    // 2. add scale animation for resizing hole
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:sender.frame];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.view.bounds];
    animation.duration = 3.0f;
    [maskLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scaleAnimation"];

    self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

My idea is adding a "hole" into modal UIView and then scale wit animation.

The problem is that it doesn't work properly. First part of code make a hole well. But scaling animation of a hole doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an animation to a layer if the layer isn't in some window's layer tree. You need to do things in this order:

```
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[CATransaction flush];
[maskLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scaleAnimation"];
```